# Any biblical passages, traditions or historical record of Virgin Mary's baptism?

Tags: virgin-mary, baptism, tradition

Jesus was already thirty years old when He said to St. John the Baptist that it is the Will of the Father that He received baptism thru his anointed hands.

St. John was baptizing Jews before Jesus came in the Jordan River. The Blessed Virgin Mary on the other hand possibly knew what was St.John the Baptist was doing, it seems the bible was silent that Mary ever approaches St.John the Baptist.

Jesus Christ fully God and fully man is willed by God to seek St.John the Baptist. How come the Blessed Virgin Mary who is a creature although Catholicism teaches she does not need to be baptize by virtue of immaculate conception. However, if Jesus who is a God-Man had to seek St. John why would Mary be exempt?

Is there a passages or teachings that Mary receive baptism or a similar ordination, so that like Jesus although not needed but it is still the Will of Father.

St. Peter teaches the importance of baptism as it will make a believer heir in the priestly office of Jesus Christ. And this will make a believer able to perform the priestly role of offering a sacrifice.

> "But you are a chosen people, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, God’s special possession, that you may declare the praises of him who called you out of darkness into his wonderful light." (1Peter2:9)

And St.Paul teaches that every believer or baptized person as member of the body of Christ the Church can offer their sacrifices united to Christ;

> "Now I rejoice in my sufferings for you, and I fill up in my flesh what is lacking in regard to Christ’s afflictions for the sake of His body, which is the church." (Collosians1:24)

If Mary did not receive baptism or some ordination from St. John the Baptist, it would mean She did not receive an anointing like what happen to Jesus Christ.

In the Old Testament only a priest can offer a sacrifice to God, if Mary did not receive baptism or ordination how can Her offering of fiat or her "body & blood" be acceptable God?

The only close passages is before Mary can utter Her Fiat, She must already receive a baptism or ordination in order for Her Fiat, like the priest in the old testament be acceptable God.

Is there any biblical passages, traditions or historical record of Virgin Mary's baptism?

Comment: There are no biblical passages of Mary's baptism. However, since she was immaculately conceived, she didn't need to be baptized.

Comment: @user96931 In my understanding of Catholic Faith, Mary's immaculate conception is the reason why Mary already have a sanctifying grace that a person receive in baptism.

Answer (score 2):

**Was the Blessed Virgin Mary Baptized?**

Scripture does not speak of it. There is not historical document or record of this ever happening. However, Catholic tradition holds that the Virgin Mary did in fact receive baptism and thus set an example for all the faithful to follow.

> According to tradition going back to the second century (documented by renowned Scripture scholar Cornelius a Lapide), Christ baptized the Blessed Virgin Mary.
>
> It is true that Blessed Mary was without original sin, and full of grace. However, she had yet received the baptismal character, which is an indelible feature of the baptized. Also, the sacrament of baptism linked her even more closely with the Church of her beloved Son.
>
> If she humbly submitted to Old Law precepts out of humility (e.g. the purification after birth), then she no doubt would also have received the sacraments of the New Law. Moreover, Mary wanted to be like Christ her Savior in all ways. Christ didn’t need baptism but He received baptism. No doubt, she desire the same. Mary didn’t need to die, but she desired to die in order to be perfectly conformed to Christ. This is a feature of all the ancient Dormition accounts.
>
> Did the Immaculate Mary need to be baptized. No, of course not.
>
> Did the Immaculate Mary want to be baptized. Yes, of course.
>
> [Was the Blessed Virgin Mary Baptized?](https://taylormarshall.com/2011/07/was-blessed-virgin-mary-baptized.html)

Would Cornelius a Lapide’s words himself suffice to prove the tradition.

Cornelius a Lapide’s [commentary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1ygPAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=Cornelius%20a%20Lapide%20baptism%20of%20mary&source=bl&ots=xBvZqVBWUX&sig=ACfU3U28KHKTs-rUWpk2eKeB14XuosyY0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI7-nZwMDnAhVBnJ4KHWxhDFYQ6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Cornelius%20a%20Lapide%20baptism%20of%20mary&f=false)

> I have need to be baptized, &c. That is, to be spiritually washed from my sins, and perfected by the Spirit of Thy grace. Have need here does not signify an obligation of precept, as though the Baptist was obliged to receive the baptism of Christ. For this precept of baptism was given and promulged by S. Peter on the Day of Pentecost, and therefore after John’s death. **Some gather from this place that John was soon afterwards baptized by Christ Himself, as were also the Blessed Virgin Mary, SS. Peter, James, and John, and the rest of the Apostles.** This is stated by S. Evodius, who succeeded S. Peter in the Chair of Antioch, in an Epistle of his, entitled τὸ φώς.
>
> In favour of this idea are also Nazian. (Orat. 39 towards the end); “Christ knew,” he says, “that He would Himself shortly afterwards baptize the Baptist;” also S. Chrysostom, who says, “John baptized Christ with water, but Christ baptized John with the Spirit.” Whence the author of the Imperfect Comment. says, “It is plainly written in apocryphal writings, that John baptized Christ with water, but He baptized John with the Spirit.”
>
> Abulensis thinks, on the other hand, that John was not baptized by Christ. And he proves it by the marvelling of John’s disciples, who soon afterwards told John that Christ, whom he had baptized, was Himself baptizing, and that all men were coming unto Him. For this would have been needlessly told to John if he had been baptized by Christ, and he would have given this reply to his disciples. So that it is a doubtful point whether John was baptized by Christ or not.

Answer (score 0):

> When they arrived, they went up into the upper room where they were staying. There were Peter as well as John and James and Andrew, Philip and Thomas, Bar·tholʹo·mew and Matthew, James the son of Al·phaeʹus, and Simon the zealous one, and Judas the son of James.+ 14 With one purpose all of these were persisting in prayer, together with some women+ and Mary the mother of Jesus and with his brothers.+. Acts 1:13,14

It seems logical that since Mary was present for the receiving of the gifts of Holy  Spirit on Pentecost that she and all those with her would have already taken the step of being baptized albeit most likely the baptism of John.

Comment: But we also don't know that Peter, James, John etc were baptised.

Answer (score -2):

Baptism is not only for being forgiven for our personal sins and the original sin, it is also to partake in the new creation!  When Jesus resurrected, his human nature was a new creation; His human nature was then united with the Divine nature in a way unknown to Adam and Eve.  Mary also died and resurrected even if she was without sin.  This means that she also suffer and died for our sins.

The true explanation for the Immaculate Conception is that her soul, as well as the soul of Adam was created on the 6th day of Creation.  Second chapter of Genesis say that Adam was made (not created); this means only his body/flesh was made.  Eve was created from Adam to be the companion of Adam, thus more vulnerable to seduction. But Mary was created    to be the Mother of God, not the companion of a man.

Comment: Welcome to [christianity.se]! Please consider citing source(s) for your claims (e.g. that Genesis 2 implies that only Adam's body/flesh was made) in order to improve your post.